# Rectangular Grid Using Google Apps Script in Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, grid-layout, google-slides-api, google-slides

So, I asked ChatGPT to create a rectangular grid using Google Apps Script within Google Slides. Here are the parameters I gave it: The grid has 5 columns and 4 rows, with each rectangle being no more than 20% of the width of the grid, which is 1880px wide. The rectangles are separated by 20px margins and the slide itself has 20px margins on the outside. It sort of worked, but I had to adjust the width and height in the script because the rectangles went beyond the width and height of the 1920 x 1080 slide. Also, when I adjust the margin and number of columns, it doesn't fit exactly like I want it to. Here's the code below that it gave me...

```
function createGrid() {
  var slideWidth = 1440;
  var slideHeight = 810;
  var margin = 20;
  var numRows = 4;
  var numColumns = 6;
  var maxRectWidth = slideWidth * 0.2; // Each rectangle is no more than 20% of the width of the grid
  var rectWidth = Math.min((slideWidth - margin * 2 - margin * (numColumns - 1)) / numColumns, maxRectWidth);
  var rectHeight = (slideHeight - margin * 2 - margin * (numRows - 1)) / numRows;
  
  // Create new slide and set dimensions
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.appendSlide();
  slide.selectAsCurrentPage();

  // Create grid of rectangles
  for (var row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
    for (var column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
      var x = margin + column * (rectWidth + margin);
      var y = margin + row * (rectHeight + margin);
      var shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.RECTANGLE, x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
      shape.getBorder().setTransparent();
      shape.getFill().setSolidFill('#777777');
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the grid it gave me. I had to adjust the `SlideWidth` and `SlideHeight` to get it to work.

[image: rectangular grid produced by Google Apps Script in Google Slides]

So, I know that the math is wrong with the formula it's using in lines 7-9 of the script, but I'm not smart enough to change it so that no matter what margins I put in there, or number of columns or rows, it would fit within the 1920 x 1080 slide with 20px margins on the outside of the slide.

**Would any of you know how to edit this script so that no matter what margin, or number of rows or columns I put in there, the rectangular grid would fit within a 1920 x 1080 slide with 20px margins on the outside?**

[Here's a link to make your own copy to view the script and its result.](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1d2P-hyex7ayECdY2RGoLyd8Nhez7NWaBNokMT1fN_nI/copy)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. In your question, you say `because the rectangles went beyond the width and height of the 1920 x 1080 slide`. But, in your script, you use `var slideWidth = 1440;` and `var slideHeight = 810;`. If those are the width and height a slide, is this related to your current issue? And, your provided Google Slide is your expected result. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike yeah, I had to adjust the width and height within the script to get it to fit on a 1920px x 1080px slide with 20px margins around the outside. But ideally, I would have 1920 x 1080 in the script, and then then math formula in lines 7-9 would automatically adjust depending upon how much margin I put, and rows and columns.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike no worries, and I think your English is pretty good. It's a difficult language to learn.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have 2 questions. 1. Is your provided Google Slide your expected result? 2. If your provided Slide is not your expected result, can you provide your expected result? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your current issue and your expected goal. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike so, I adjusted the SlideWidth and SlideHeight to equal what I'm wanting, which is 1920 x 1080 pixels. So, I'm looking for a solution that whatever margin size I choose, or rows, or columns, the width and height of the rectangles will always adjust to fit the 1920 x 1080 pixel slide with whatever margin size is specified on line 4 of the script. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure about the size of the slide?  What if a different browser produces a smaller slide.  Why not try this.

```
let presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
let slides = presentation.getSlides();
let slide = slides[0];

let slideWidth = presentation.getPageWidth();
let slideHeight = presentation.getPageHeight();
let margin = 20;
let numRows = 5;
let numColumns = 4;
let rectWidth = (slideWidth - margin * 2 - margin * (numColumns - 1)) / numColumns;
let rectHeight = (slideHeight - margin * 2 - margin * (numRows - 1)) / numRows;

// Create grid of rectangles
for (let row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
  for (let column = 0; column < numColumns; column++) {
    let x = margin + column * (rectWidth + margin);
    let y = margin + row * (rectHeight + margin);
    let shape = slide.insertShape(SlidesApp.ShapeType.RECTANGLE, x, y, rectWidth, rectHeight);
    shape.getBorder().setTransparent();
    shape.getFill().setSolidFill('#777777');
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try that. It's more for me. Are you saying that this code you're providing will adjust depending upon the user's screen dimensions?

Comment: Not sure where to put this though, because I'm getting an error.

Comment: So, it seems to work, but then when you change the rows to 5 and columns to 4, it doesn't stretch to fit the slide.

Comment: Its because you also have limit width to 20% of slide width which is less than `slideWidth - margin * 2 - margin * (numColumns - 1)) / numColumns`

Comment: Ok, thanks for letting me know. I think that's the issue that needs to be resolved, but not sure what to change the formula to.

Comment: I've replace the code with the entire working code

Comment: It works great! But, I decided to take out the first 3 lines of your code and replaced it with what I initially had so that it will always append, creating a new slide after I run the script.

`// Create new slide and set dimensions
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide = presentation.appendSlide();
  slide.selectAsCurrentPage();`